# differences in for loops in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, for-loop, range

can someone explain why these two loops look like they do the same thing, when in fact the second version doesn't find the duplicate number correctly?

```
list1 = [1,2,13,4,6,6,8,11,10]

for i in range(len(list1)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(list1)):
            if list1[i] == list1[j]:
                print i, j
                print True
            else:
                print False
print "--------------------------------------"

for i in list1:
    for j in list1:
        if i == j + 1:
            print True, i, j
        else:
            print False
```

Comment: `i+1` is the big difference, it starts from the element at index `i+1`, in the second loop `if i == j + 1:` just adds 1 to the value of j, it does not check the j'th + 1 element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in range(len(list1)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(list1)):
            if list1[i] == list1[j]:
                print i, j
                print True
            else:
                print False
```

The code above iterates over a list which is generated by the `range()` function which returns a list of numbers that in your case is `[0,1,2,....,len(list1) - 1]` in the first loop.
In the second loop the list that you go over is `[i + 1, i + 2, i + 3,...,len(list1) - 1]`. 
 On every iteration `i` and `j`are assigned to one item of the list just like a normal `for` loop (Java, C#, C++ and more).

---

```
for i in list1:
    for j in list1:
        if i == j + 1:
            print True, i, j
        else:
            print False
```

In this code `i` and `j` are assigned to each item **value** in `list1`.

On every iteration `i` and `j` will be assigned to the next item value in the list, **NOT THE POSITION**.
In your case `i` value will be `1` then `2` then `13`... Same applies to `j`.

Answer (score 1):

They don't do the same thing at all. The second one loops through the whole of list1 in the inner loop, instead of just from the current index onwards. And, for some reason, you add 1 to the value before comparing, so it wouldn't be equal.